# Gravar dados temporários no array ou consultar a base de dados

Tags: lógica

É necessário verificar se o utilizador tem permissão para ver/editar dados de um determinado cliente.

Essa verificação ocorre em quase todas as operações do aplicação.

Atualmente ao fazer login na aplicação, faço uma única consulta a base de dados e verifico quais os clientes que estão associados ao utilizador e gravo em uma sessão.

Quando é necessário verificar se o utilizador tem permissão para ver/editar dados do cliente, faço um FOR na sessão e verifico se o ID do cliente existe.

Acontece que há utilizadores com permissão para ver/editar 5 clientes e a outros com 300.
Gravar em sessão e fazer um FOR será sempre mais rápido do que uma consulta a base de dados?

**OBS**.: a integridade dos dados não é uma preocupação, apenas se a leitura de um array será mais rápida que da leitura a base de dados.

Comment: E se você utilizasse uma ACL (Access Control List)? [Nesse](https://github.com/hjpbarcelos/spice-acl#usage), por exemplo, feito em PHP, você criaria o *Handler* e uma *Role* para o usuário logado e, então, adicionaria um *resource* (adição, edição...) para cada cliente que o usuário teria permissões. Se algum *resource*, de algum cliente, for proibido, como exclusão, você criaria uma regra de negação. E em cada página você verificaria as permissões e autorizaria ou não.

Answer (score 2):

O que acontece se durante a seção um novo cliente é removido ou autorizado para esse usuário logado? 
Da forma que você está fazendo caso o usuário nunca saia do sistema ele nunca irá perder acessos ou adquirir novos acessos.

Faça as consultas sempre que necessário, assim você garante que o usuário sempre estará fazendo o que pode e não estará fazendo o que não pode.

Por mais que você perca alguns microssegundos executando a consulta, esta falha pode comprometer a integridade geral do sistema.

Comment: Na verdade a própria pergunta já responde: Se o dado é TEMPORÁRIO não tem sentido guardar em cache. Agora uma ressalva é que consultas em memória são bem mais rápidas que consultas em disco, logo dizer que ele irá perder apenas**alguns micro segundos** é um tanto leviano.

Comment: Independente de quanto tempo ele perca, manter a integridade do sistema com certeza é mais importante.

Comment: Mas quem disse que isso vai causar algum inconsistência? E se essas informações não mudarem com frequência? Não existe bala de prata parceiro. Cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Certo, mas isso já foi pensado, sempre que o utilizador perde acesso a um cliente, automaticamente a sua sessão é finalizada. Outro ponto é que essa informação não muda com frequência.

Comment: Então esta resposta já cai por terra. Não se aplica.

Comment: Na verdade essas informações são importantes, e devem estar na pergunta, quem está respondendo não tem como deduzir como é o funcionamento do seu software

Comment: Outra coisa, com isso você perde muito com usabilidade na sua aplicação, sempre que o nível de acesso mudar terei que entrar novamente no sistema? É isso ou entendi errado?

Comment: @ErlonCharles sim, porém não é algo que irá mudar com frequência, serão casos raros.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve medir o que é mais importante no seu sistema e quais são as consequências de cada decisão.

1. **Consultar o banco de dados** garante que seu sistema não irá sofrer com possíveis inconsistências que podem vir a ocorrer caso alguma dessas regras de acesso venha a mudar ao longo da sessão.

Buscar no banco de dados é mais fácil e seguro, fato. Porém é caro e muitas consultas podem comprometer a performance do seu sistema.

2. **Consulta In-Memory:** Se esta estrutura de permissões é algo que dificilmente irá mudar eu não vejo problemas de se trabalhar com registros em memória. Consultas in memory são infinitamente mais rápidas que consultas em disco (no caso, banco de dados).

Na maioria dos casos procurar um elemento na lista será mais rápido que buscar um elemento na base de dados, mas não é 100% correto pois existem técnicas e situações que podem melhorar ou piorar a performance, como por exemplo a criação de índices no banco, uso de listas otimizadas para pesquisa podem optimizar a busca. A lista ser muito grande e o elemento pode estar no final dela e um banco mal projetado pode deixar a busca mais lenta.

Eu particularmente trabalharia com dados **in-memory** se estivesse com um cenário como o seu.. São muitos fatores e você deve levar tudo isso em consideração.

Comment: Essa sua última frase me faz pensar em qualificar essa pergunta como principalmente baseada em opiniões.

Comment: Não é muito o caso. Apesar de existirem muitas variáveis é possível chegar a uma solução. O cenário esta bem descrito.